# How to download file with directory in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

```
url = 'www.xyz.com/video/2020/bio/file.mp4'
```

how to download file.mp4 by in terminal by making directory video/2020/bio and download file inside this directory "bio"

can't do manualy because i have more than 200 url with different directory like => video/2020/chem , video/2021/bio, video/2020/maths.

Solved

```
#!/bin/bash
file=list.txt
for i in `cat $file`
do
 URL=$i
 URL_NOPRO=${URL:7}
 URL_REL=${URL_NOPRO#*/}
 pi=${URL_REL%%\?*}
 mkdir -p "${pi%/*}"
 wget $URL -P "${pi%/*}"
done
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried?

Comment: #!/bin/bash;
file=list.txt;
for i in `cat $file`;
do;
wget "$i" ;
done

Comment: Please add this code/comment to your question, so others can easily see what you've tried to solve your problem. And maybe add the error messages or what you've done and why it didn't work.

Comment: `url = 'www.xyz.com/video/2020/bio/file.mp4'` is a syntax error (you can't have spaces around the equals sign); is this actual code you are attempting to run?

Answer (score 1):

`wget` does something like this automatically with an option, but the options are unwieldy; it is easy to do the things the developer likes, but hard to do something slightly different.

For example,

```
wget -x http://example.site/path/to/file.html
```

will create the directory path `example.site/path/to` and save `file.html` in the leaf directory.

`wget -x -nH` will omit the `example.site` directory and create `path/to/file.html`

With `curl`, you seem to be looking for

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
    # trim off protocol part if present (maybe add more cases for ftp:// etc)
    path=${url#http://}
    path=${url#https://}
    # then trim up to first remaining slash
    path=${url#*/}
    mkdir -p "${path%/*}"
    curl -o "$path" "$url"
done <"$file"
```

Notice also the use of a `while` loop; [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Putting the file name in a variable does not seem to offer any benefit in this isolated case, but perhaps you have a reason to want that.

Comment: getting error=>"bash: line 10: : No such file or directory"  [  line10 : curl -o "$path" "$url" ]

Comment: You obviously need to install `curl` if you want to use it.

Comment: Answer updated; I looked up the options in the `wget` manual page for you. In case you had trouble finding it, here: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html